# Was the plot of 'The One' (2001) influenced by 'Highlander'?

Tags: inspiration, highlander, highlander-franchise, the-one

The two plots seem very similar:

> A sheriff's deputy fights an alternate universe version of himself *who grows stronger with each alternate self he kills.*

Obviously it's taking form the age old trope of 'What ever you kill makes you stronger' (the oldest example I can think of is tales of eating dragon hearts to strengthen you).

But have the writers/producers/people involved ever said that *Highlander* was a direct inspiration? If not are there any other clues from either film that tie them together?

Comment: It seemed like 'The One' bastardized many movies besides just Highlander, especially 'Timecop', 'The Matrix', and a couple X-Files episodes.

Comment: Isn't imitation supposedly the highest form of praise? Regardless, I enjoyed the film.

Comment: Timecop was so bad that if you manage to steal from it and still have a watchable movie, it's not so much theft as it is eminent domain for the public benefit.

Comment: I've never seen time cop, but it sounds most excellent.

Comment: The concept is less whatever you kill makes you stronger and more http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu As each version is killed the "power" is distributed to the remaining instances of the individual.

Comment: @jonita, IU odn't think thats how CoN works, nor are most of the fight seens many to one, IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only cast/crew connection between the two films is that they share a stunt director named [Gregory J. Barnett](https://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0267804,tt0091203). 'The One' also shared a Casting Director with the TV series 'Highlander'.

Frankly 'The One' is such a grotesque mish-mash of stolen movie concepts and [tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheOne)  that it's hard to pin down any specific inspiration. I've not seen any indication that the screenplay (as written by Glenn Morgan) was directly inspired by 'Highlander' although it's very likely he would have seen it a few years before he wrote the screenplay.

Comment: Warning, contains TV Tropes Link.